# Implement test which tries function with diferent params and expected results

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++03

What could I improve in the following code? The goal is to test a function againts a table of input parameters and compare to some expected results with some tolerance (as there are random variables involved in the computations).

This is how I am doing it right now. Note that I cannot use any C++11 features.

```
void test() throw (const char *) {

    const double TOLERANCE = 0.01;

    const double EXPIRY_TESTS[] = {0.0, more values...};
    const double STRIKE_TESTS[] = { 0.0, more values... };
    const double SPOT_TESTS[] = { 0.0, more values... };
    const double VOL_TESTS[] = { 0.0, more values... };
    const double R_TESTS[] = { 0.0, more values... };
    const unsigned long NPATHS_TESTS[] = { 1, more values... };
    const double EXPECTED_RESULTS[] = { 0.0, more values... };

    int i_result = 0;
    for (int i0 = 0; i0 < sizeof(EXPIRY_TESTS) / sizeof(double); i0++) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < sizeof(STRIKE_TESTS) / sizeof(double); i1++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < sizeof(SPOT_TESTS) / sizeof(double); i2++) {
                for (int i3 = 0; i3 < sizeof(VOL_TESTS) / sizeof(double); i3++) {
                    for (int i4 = 0; i4 < sizeof(R_TESTS) / sizeof(double); i4++) {
                        for (int i5 = 0; i5 < sizeof(NPATHS_TESTS) / sizeof(long); i5++) {

                            double result = SimpleMonteCarlo1(EXPIRY_TESTS[i0], 
                                                              STRIKE_TESTS[i1], 
                                                              SPOT_TESTS[i2], 
                                                              VOL_TESTS[i3], 
                                                              R_TESTS[i4], 
                                                              NPATHS_TESTS[i5]);
                            if (abs(EXPECTED_RESULTS[i_result] - result) >= TOLERANCE) {
                                throw "Test failed!";
                            }
                            i_result++;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Approximately how many values?

Comment: About 3-8 values per parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A six-fold nesting is not a way to go. Enumerating all possible combinations can be achieved in two loops, no matter how many arrays are contributing:

  ```
  bool next_combination(int * combination, int * limits, int size) {
      for (int index = 0; index < size; ++index) {
          combination[index] += 1;
          if (combination[index] < limits[index]) {
              return true;
          }
          combination[index] = 0;
      }
      return false;
  }

  ...

  int limits[] = { countof(EXPIRY_TEST), countof(STRIKE_TEST), /*etc*/ };
  int combination[countof(limits)] = 0;

  do {
      result = function(EXPIRY_TEST[combination[0], STRIKE_TEST[combination[1], /*etc*/);
  while (next_combination(combination, limits, countof(combination)));
  ```
- Size of array is better be computed in a type-agnostic way:

  ```
  #define countof(name) (sizeof(name) / sizeof(name[0]))
  ```
- The expected results are totally disconnected from the argument sets. It would be very hard to make additional cases.
- You must report *which* test case failed.